# Add path to Filza (logos)

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, theos, cydia-substrate, logos

I am trying this code on a jailbroken device (iOS 8.4), but Filza opens without navigating to the location I specified (it just shows the last location I was in):

```
NSString *path = @"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0037F06A-A2C5-491C-A4E8-CB5DAFBA6415/Facebook.app";

NSString *FilzaPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"Filza://",path];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FilzaPath]];
```

Is there anything wrong with this code, or is it that Filza doesn't support this? I looked around and found nothing to help, but I know it can be done since iClearner has a similar feature to open preference files in Filza/iFile. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of work on IDA, I was able to figure out that in order to open a file in Filza, you have to use the following URL scheme: `"filza://view".`

**Final code will be:**

```
     NSString *path = @"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0037F06A-A2C5-491C-A4E8-CB5DAFBA6415/Facebook.app";

     NSString *FilzaPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"Filza://view",path];

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FilzaPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I logged out your path and it looks like this:

> Filza:////private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0037F06A-A2C5-491C-A4E8-CB5DAFBA6415/Facebook.app

Is that the correct path you intended? Seems like there is an extra slash or two at the start.
(sorry, I can't comment until I get 50 points)

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I removed one of the slashes, but still the same. The thing is, I tried contacting Filza support/iCleaner dev, but they won't reply back. Searching the net, I saw other references for iFile like "iFile://+path", so that's why I am basing it on that, but it's not working!